# How to import or connect PostgreSQL data into virtuoso

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, virtuoso

I have the data from PostgreSQL, and I exported the data via `pg_dump` and now I want to import this data into Virtuoso.

I tried to import data via Virtuoso Conductor/Linked Data/Quad Store Upload, 
but I get following as it doesn't support the data -

> You have attempted to upload invalid data. 
>   You can only upload RDF, Turtle, N3 serializations of RDF Data to the RDF Data Store.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You can't just import output from `pg_dump` into a completely different database engine. The error message specifies the formats it accepts. You will need to transform the data, probably by querying it from PostgreSQL. Look into ETL and data import tools.

Comment: You might consider the [Commercial Edition of Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/), which will let you create [remote Linked Data VIEWs of the data which remains in PostgreSQL](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPgrRDFViewUI).  Or you could use the [Commercial Edition's Replication features](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/repl.html) to import the data from PostgreSQL via ODBC.  Among other options.